# Xamarin binding for Brightcove player SDK, Error The type or namespace name `BCOVMutableCuePoint' could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, xamarin.ios, brightcove

I am trying to build Xamarin binding for [Brightcove player SDK](https://github.com/brightcove/brightcove-player-sdk-ios) and after referring to the [binding guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/), I have developed iOS binding project for it (please check it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2PhjAtycyPncTdoRkZJeUh1OUE&authuser=0)). But while compiling binding project I am facing 28 error which are of same type-

> /Users/amber/Projects/BrightCoveBinding/BrightCoveBinding/obj/Debug/ios/BrightCoveBinding/BCOVCuePoint.g.cs(118,118):
>   Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `BCOVMutableCuePoint' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246) (BrightCoveBinding)

But, I have written interface for `BCOVMutableCuePoint` type in `ApiDefinition.cs` file. Please, can anyone guide regarding this where I am doing wrong or what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Xamarin, but it's possible that Xamarin doesn't like the fact that in the Brightcove Player SDK for iOS, `BCOVMutableCuePoint` is used both as a protocol name *and* a class name. [You only see the protocol in the header file](https://github.com/brightcove/brightcove-player-sdk-ios/blob/master/Headers%2FBCOVCuePoint.h#L86-L92), but there is also an Objective-C class (`@interface`) with that name in the library's object code. Maybe this will be of some help in troubleshooting your Xamarin problem.